# What is javac internal?

Tags: 15.04, java, openjdk

I just installed a new version of Java 8, when I asked for the version of the Java I got following output

```
~/$ javac -version
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar 
javac 1.8.0_45-internal
```

I understood javac version 1.8 but what is `internal`, this word didn't appeared when I installed Java 8 by external PPAs (earlier). This time I installed OpenJDK8 without external PPAs